# Sending Server Push with Continuation frame in Apache

Tags: apache, http2, push-promise

I'm testing my HTTP/2 parser and currently I'm having trouble testing push promise with continuation. I'm using Apache as the HTTP/2 server. I managed to push a resource using either `Location`'s `Header add link` or `H2PushResource`. But when I tried to check push promise with continuation I couldn't modify the headers sent in the pushed request.
I wanted to add a few long headers for the pushed request but the commands I found didn't affect the pushed request:

- [RequestHeader](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) modifies the request headers before the content is handled - This means that the header is modified inside Apache's HTTP parser, it doesn't affect the sent pushed request
- [Header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header) modifies the response headers sent from the server - This command adds a header to the **response**, not the request

**Edit:**
I noticed that the `user-agent` header is also sent in the pushed request, so I sent a *really* long user-agent header in my request but then I got a 431 response ([Request header field too large](https://httpstatusdogs.com/431-request-header-fields-too-large)).
Any other idea?

**Edit 2:**
Here are my HTTP/2 configuration lines:

```
<Location /push.html>
    H2PushResource add "/push.png"
</Location>
Header set MyRespHeader "Testing response"
RequestHeader add MyReqHeader "Testing request"
```

When I receive a response from Apache I get the header `myrespheader` but the pushed request doesn't send the header `myreqheader` or `myrespheader`

Comment: What do you mean "don't affect the pushed request?" How do you know? Please explain clearly what you have attempted to do and why you believe it's not working.

Comment: I elaborated a bit. Is it clear now?

Comment: No. Please show the config you have used and why you believe it's not working. It should be sent as a Response header and mod_http2 jumps in and also pushes the resource. Alternatively you can use H2PushResource rather than using headers. Either way you should use the 'as' option to ensure a pushed resource is used and not downloaded again. I've a blog post on it here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/http2-push/

Comment: At the moment I don't know if you are struggling to get Push to work at all (as you seem confused whether to set on incoming or outgoing headers), or only with continuation frames. Or why you even think there is a problem with push on continuation frames.

Comment: I modified the question to answer some of the confusion. What do you mean the 'as' option? It couldn't find a reference to it in your blog post or Apache's mod_http2 documentation

Comment: I see you are using H2PushResource rather than link headers so ignore my comments on 'as' option. Your code looks fine. What version of Apache are you using? And what browser and version? Also I do not understand why you expect the pushed resource to send the MyReqHeader - this is added to the request just before it is processed so Apache (or any downstream system if using Apache in front of it) will get this header - it does not mean it will be returned in the response.

Comment: The server is `Apache/2.4.25 (Unix)` and I'm using command line browser `nghttp2/1.17.0`. Why does it matter? The browser choice shouldn't affect the behavior of the server's pushes. I understand why myreqheader isn't shown, I tried to explain it in the original post. It was an example of a possible solution (that failed) for the problem (adding headers to the pushed request, so CONTINUATION frames will be added to PUSH_PROMISE frame)

Comment: It matters because some browsers (e.g. Safari) don't support push. And neither does certain versions of nghttp (https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/issues/21). This is why it is helpful to give as much detail as possible! Does push work in Chrome? That will help show if it's a client or server problem.

Comment: I don't have an issue with sending server push, this works fine. I'm having trouble adding headers to the pushed request. I want to add headers to the pushed request because this will allow me to inflate the pushed request to make Apache send a push request with a continuation frame

Comment: OK now I finally understand the question you are asking. Can you clarify the last line though "When I receive a response from Apache I get the header myrespheader but the pushed request doesn't send the header myreqheader". Does the pushed request include myrespheader? If so doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146530/discussion-between-earthdragon-and-bazzadp).